# Laravel - adding relationships to a factory-created model

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, phpunit

I am testing an eager loading relationship which contains many to many relations. Right now I have the queries and attachments within the test. I'm wondering if there is a way to move them into the factory, rather than including it as part of your test. This would limit the size of the test and then these relations could be created and used every time a film factory is created.

**`test`**

```
public function grabFilmTest()
{
    $film = factory(Film::class)->create();

    $categories = Category::where('main-cat', 'Science')->where('sub-cat', 'Fiction')->first();
    $languages = Languages::where('name', 'english')->first();

    $film->categories()->attach($categories->id);
    $film->languages()->attach($languages->id);

    $response = $this->json('GET', '/film/' . $film->id)
        ->assertStatus(200);

    $response
        ->assertExactJson([
            'id' => $film->id,
            'name' => $film->name,
            'description' => $film->description,
            'categories' => $film->categories->toArray(),
            'languages' => $film->languages->toArray()

}
```

**`filmFactory`**

```
$factory->define(\App\Models\Film::class, function (Faker $faker){
    return [
        'id' => $faker->uuid,
        'name' => $faker->text,
        'description' => $faker->paragraph,
    ];
});
```

If anyone could help with how i could do this or an example it would be great :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keeping the old answer for posterity below, but this is what the equivalent factory class would look like in modern versions of Laravel:

```php
<?php

namespace Database\Factories;

use App\Models\Film;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\Factory;

class FilmFactory extends Factory
{
    protected $model = Film::class;

    public function definition(): array
    {
        return [
            'id'          => $this->faker->uuid,
            'name'        => $this->faker->text,
            'description' => $this->faker->paragraph,
        ];
    }

    public function configure(): static
    {
        return $this->afterCreating(function (Film $film) {
            $category = Category::where('main-cat', 'Science')
                ->where('sub-cat', 'Fiction')
                ->first();
            $film->categories()->attach($category);

            $language = Languages::where('name', 'english')
                ->first();
            $film->languages()->attach($language);
        });
    }
}
```

---

You can use [factory callbacks](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/database-testing#factory-callbacks) to do it in the factory file:

```
<?php
use \App\Models\Film;
use \App\Models\Category;
use \App\Models\Languages;

$factory->define(Film::class, function(Faker $faker){
    return [
        'id'          => $faker->uuid,
        'name'        => $faker->text,
        'description' => $faker->paragraph,
    ];
});

$factory->afterCreating(Film::class, function(Film $film, Faker $faker) {
    $category = Category::where('main-cat', 'Science')->where('sub-cat', 'Fiction')->first();
    $language = Languages::where('name', 'english')->first();
    $film->categories()->attach($category);
    $film->languages()->attach($language);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use [factory states](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/database-testing#factory-states) and [factory callbacks](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/database-testing#factory-callbacks).

```
$factory->define(\App\Models\Film::class, function (Faker $faker){
    return [
        'id' => $faker->uuid,
        'name' => $faker->text,
        'description' => $faker->paragraph,
    ];
});
$factory->define(\App\Models\Category::class, function (Faker $faker){
    return [
        // Category fields 
    ];
});
$factory->define(\App\Models\Language::class, function (Faker $faker){
    return [
        // Language fields 
    ];
});
$factory->afterCreatingState(\App\Models\Film::class, 'with-category', function (\App\Models\Film $film) {
    $category = factory(\App\Models\Category::class)->create();
    $film->categories()->attach($category->id);
});
$factory->afterCreatingState(\App\Models\Film::class, 'with-language', function (\App\Models\Film $film) {
    $language = factory(\App\Models\Language::class)->create();
    $film->categories()->attach($language->id);
});
```

Then you can use in tests like this:

```
public function grabFilmTest()
{
    $film = factory(Film::class)->create();
    $filmWithCategory = factory(Film::class)->state('with-category')->create();
    $filmWithLanguage = factory(Film::class)->state('with-language')->create();
    $filmWithCategoryAnLanguage = factory(Film::class)->states(['with-category', 'with-language'])->create();
    // ...
}
```

PS: I don't recommend using existing data. From experience, I can tell you that can become really painful.

Comment: thanks for the example :) what experiences did you come across that made it painful?

Comment: I inherited a large Laravel app (there are around 175 models with relations). We use seeders to populate test DB. Pain points: 1) seeders maintenance. When you already have seeders and tests depending on these, a small schema/model change will force you to change all the seeders or previous tests. And if your model has relationships the change it getting harder and harder. 2) In some cases, you need clean tables for your tests. Cleaning a table and running the seeder again (to not break exiting tests) it's a redundant job. Also, relationships bring even more pain.